# Is sending IP Address as a parameter with a POST request from a client to a rails server safe?

Tags: ip, rails

I am trying to get the IP address and send it to my rails server as a parameter of a POST request. Is this action safe?

Comment: more context...what is the IP address for? I dont see why it would be unsafe, if you are unsure just send it via https?

Comment: it depends on what you then want to do with that address (and also what address it is), so yeah, much more details are needed

Comment: Im sending the IP Address of a mobile device to the rails server. Not sure if it is a secure practice?

Comment: can you elaborate what you want to achieve by this?

Comment: Safe against what?

Answer (score 2):

There's no utility on sending IP address of local device, on which you app is running. There're good chances that you'll get only local ip-address from the device, which is hardly useful. Moreover, in the days of dynamic public IP address assignment from ISPs, IP addresses are hardly used for monitoring or tracking purpose(As there're good chances that public IP address assigned to you by your ISP, may be assigned to some other computer, at another time).

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the data is 'safely' POSTed to your server such that it remains confidential and is not tampered with by an attacker in transit, use transport layer security (TLS).

To ensure that your application 'safely' processes the POSTed data, validate that data prior to use to ensure it is what you expect to receive i.e an IP Address.